# Scalar variable issue not being able to use in Select Query SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I 'm not able to use both `Declare` statements in my select query when I do the insert into.

1. How do you use a column itemId to be set in a another column called id?
2. How do you write a same string to a specific column?
3. Why can't I call my scalar variable ?

```
DECLARE @Solutions_id as INT 
DECLARE @Solutions_name as nvarchar(50)

INSERT INTO ticket_historical_actions
(
[id]
,[type]
[Solutions _rowId]
,[Solutions_dw_dateCreate]
      ,[Solutions_dw_dateMod]
      ,[Solutions_dw_dateDelete] 
      ,[Solutions_sourceId]
      ,[Solutions_date_create]
      ,[Solutions_date_mod]
      ,[Solutions_date_approval]
      ,[Solutions_itemId]
      ,[Solutions_solutionTypeName] 
      ,[Solutions_content_plainText] 
      ,[Solutions_userId]  
      ,[Solutions_userId_editor]
      ,[Solutions_userId_approval]
      ,[Solutions_userName]
      ,[Solutions_userName_approval] 
      ,[Solutions_status]
       ,[Ticket_rowId]
,[Ticket_dw_dateCreate] 
      ,[Ticket_dw_dateMod]
      ,[Ticket_dw_dateDelete] 
      ,[Ticket_sourceId]
      ,[Ticket_date_create]
      ,[Ticket_date_mod] 
      ,[Ticket_date_close] 
      ,[Ticket_date_solve] 
      ,[Ticket_entityId] 
      ,[Ticket_name] 
      ,[Ticket_date] 
      ,[Ticket_status]
      ,[Ticket_is_deleted] 
      ,[Ticket_content_PlainText] 
      ,[Ticket_type]
      ,[Ticket_urgency] 
      ,[Ticket_impact] 
      ,[Ticket_priority] 
      ,[Ticket_requestTypeId] 
      ,[Ticket_userId_lastUpdater]
      ,[Ticket_userId_recipient] 
      ,[Ticket_time_to_resolve] 
      ,[Ticket_time_to_own] 
        ,[Users_rowId] 
,[Users_dw_dateCreate] 
      ,[Users_dw_dateMod]
      ,[Users_dw_dateDelete] 
      ,[Users_sourceId] 
      ,[Users_date_create]
      ,[Users_date_mod] 
      ,[Users_name] 
      ,[Users_LastName] 
      ,[Users_firstName] 
      ,[Users_phone] 
      ,[Users_mobile] 
      ,[Users_language] 
      ,[Users_profileId] 
      ,[Users_entitieId] 
      ,[Users_titleId] 
      ,[Users_categoryId]
      ,[Users_managerId] 
  ,[Company_rowId]
, [Company_dw_dateCreate] 
      ,[Company_dw_dateMod]  
      ,[Company_dw_dateDelete] 
      ,[Company_sourceId]
      ,[Company_date_mod]
      ,[Company_date_create] 
      ,[Company_completename] 
      ,[Company_name] 
      ,[Company_address]
      ,[Company_postcode] 
      ,[Company_town] 
      ,[Company_state] 
      ,[Company_country] 
      ,[Company_phonenumber] 
      ,[Company_email] 
      ,[Company_admin_email]  
      ,[Company_admin_name] 

    
)


SELECT
@Solutions_id =[itemId], @Solutions_name = 'Solutions',
ts.[rowId]  
      ,ts.[dw_dateCreate]
      ,ts.[dw_dateMod]
      ,ts.[dw_dateDelete]
      ,ts.[sourceId]
      ,ts.[date_create]
      ,ts.[date_mod]
      ,ts.[date_approval]
      ,ts.[itemId]
      ,ts.[solutionTypeName]
      ,ts.[content_plainText]
      ,ts.[userId]
      ,ts.[userId_editor]
      ,ts.[userId_approval]
      ,ts.[userName]
      ,ts.[userName_approval]
      ,ts.[status]
, tt. [rowId]
      ,tt.[dw_dateCreate]
      ,tt.[dw_dateMod]
      ,tt.[dw_dateDelete]
      ,tt.[sourceId]
      ,tt.[date_create]
      ,tt.[date_mod]
      ,tt.[date_close]
      ,tt.[date_solve]
      ,tt.[entityId]
      ,tt.[name]
      ,tt.[date]
      ,tt.[status]
      ,tt.[is_deleted]
      ,tt.[content_PlainText]
      ,tt.[type]
      ,tt.[urgency]
      ,tt.[impact]
      ,tt.[priority]
      ,tt.[requestTypeId]
      ,tt.[userId_lastUpdater]
      ,tt.[userId_recipient]
      ,tt.[time_to_resolve]
      ,tt.[time_to_own]
, tu.[rowId]
      ,tu.[dw_dateCreate]
      ,tu.[dw_dateMod]
      ,tu.[dw_dateDelete]
      ,tu.[sourceId]
      ,tu.[date_create]
      ,tu.[date_mod]
      ,tu.[name]
      ,tu.[LastName]
      ,tu.[firstName]
      ,tu.[phone]
      ,tu.[mobile]
      ,tu.[language]
      ,tu.[profileId]
      ,tu.[entitieId]
      ,tu.[titleId]
      ,tu.[categoryId]
      ,tu.[managerId]
, tc. [rowId]
      ,tc.[dw_dateCreate]
      ,tc.[dw_dateMod]
      ,tc.[dw_dateDelete]
      ,tc.[sourceId]
      ,tc.[date_mod]
      ,tc.[date_create]
      ,tc.[completename]
      ,tc.[name]
      ,tc.[address]
      ,tc.[postcode]
      ,tc.[town]
      ,tc.[state]
      ,tc.[country]
      ,tc.[phonenumber]
      ,tc.[email]
      ,tc.[admin_email]
      ,tc.[admin_name]
FROM
ticket_ticketSolutions ts
left join ticket_tickets tt
on ts.itemId =tt.sourceId
left join ticket_users tu
on ts.userId = tu.sourceId
left join ticket_company tc
on tu.entitieId = tc.sourceId
```

Would tell me if possible how to do it?
Thank you very much.

Comment: You already [asked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68816837/sql-error-declare-function-string-in-select-not-possible) this yesterday. Maybe, if you explain what you are trying to accomplish you'll get more useful answers

Comment: Did you write all that code without trying it once during the process?!?

Comment: Make it easy to assist you - simplify! [mcve].

Comment: because there are many isert into and i need to have a general id for all , and what kind of object is it

Comment: It's *still* the same problem as [I told you](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68816837/sql-error-declare-function-string-in-select-not-possible#comment121619125_68816837) last time. You're trying to **assign variables** in the same statement you're trying to return a data set. *You can't do that*. Assignment to variables *must* be in a separate statement to statements that return result sets

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm just going to answer, even though I have stated this in the comments of both your questions.

The problem here is you are trying to *assign* a value to your variables in the same statement you are trying to return a dataset; in T-SQL that in not allowed.

In short, you have something like this:

```sql
SELECT @MyVariable = SomeColumn,
       AnotherColumn
FROM dbo.YourTable
WHERE ID = 'SomeID';
```

So you want to return the value of `AnotherColumn` to the presentation layer, but assign the value of `SomeColumn` to the variable `@MyVariable`; you can't do this.

Instead, you *have* to use 2 statements:

```sql
SELECT @MyVariable = SomeColumn --Assigns the value to @MyVariable
FROM dbo.YourTable
WHERE ID = 'SomeID';

SELECT AnotherColumn --Returns the dataset to the presentation layer
FROM dbo.YourTable
WHERE ID = 'SomeID';
```